# Cannot execute a PDO statement (update a MySQL table) when everything else in PDO works

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is my first question on StackOverflow, can you please explain to me what I am doing wrong from: I have this code (below) but for some reason, that I have tried to look into and debug, I cannot see why PDO is not completing the request below, it works fine the same way for inserting and echoing, can someone please tell me what's going on? I am pulling my hair out of my head in frustration.

```
    $q = "UPDATE content SET urlid=:url, title=:title, description=:desc, keywords=:key     WHERE urlid=:urlid";
    $query = $pdo->prepare($q);
    $query->execute(array(
        ':url'     => $urlid,
        ':title'   => $title,
        ':desc'    => $desc,
        ':key'     => $key,
        ':contloc' => $contloc,
        ':userid'  => $uid,
        ':urlid'   => $urlid
        //':content' => $content
    ));
```

I receive the following warning in my Apache error log:

> [Thu Jul 12 21:07:13 2012] [error] [client 99.230.122.54] PHP Warning:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default/addto2.php on line 31, referer: `http://localhost/sample/4fff30aea1f20`

Comment: Thanks for the help @redelman431 but... it didn't work for me. I did find the answer here though.

Comment: Lol, yes, it is important to have only the correct number of parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$q = "UPDATE content SET urlid=:url, title=:title, description=:desc, keywords=:key WHERE urlid=:urlid";
$query = $pdo->prepare($q);
$query->execute(array(
    ':url'     => $urlid,
    ':title'   => $title,
    ':desc'    => $desc,
    ':key'     => $key,
    ':urlid'   => $urlid
));
```

PDO complains because you are passing more arguments than you are using in your query. Or perhaps you meant to include more arguments in your query and you forgot?

Comment: I was passing too many arguments as I used this code with little modification before but this time I was using it a bit differently :D

Comment: For a Newb, its big, I was frustrated for about 30 minutes on just that! Well, its solved and I know I will be coming to StackOverflow more and more.

Comment: Probably you should turn error reporting on btw, that will make your life easier since you won't have to check the logs everytime.

Comment: I don't know how to do that... can you tell me? I think I can edit the httpd.conf but I don't know what to edit.

Comment: You'll have to edit your php.ini (located in the php folder) and add the line: error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT